# Matlab for loop - How to index?

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm pretty rusty with Matlab programming and I'm stuck writing a `for` loop. I want to generate `n` random numbers using the formula `x(i+1)=mod(a*x(i), m);`

What I have is

```
for i=1:n
    x(i+1)=mod(a*x(i),m);
end
```

What I don't know, is

- How do I set `x`?
- Once I set `x`, would the index be correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should preallocate `x` for a case like this. Given your `for` loop, the minimum index is `1` and maximum index is `n+1` so `x` needs to be a vector with `n+1` elements. You could use `zeros`, for example:

```
x = zeros(n+1,1); % An n+1 by 1 column vector
```

It looks like you should also set the value of `x(1)` to some kind of initial value too. Your `for` loop is effectively a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) where the `i+1`-th value of `x` depends on the `i`-th value.